# How to Calculate Employment Experience with Special Case

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to calculate the years of experience

Let's say someone has multiple employments as follow:

```
startdate       enddate
2007-08-27      2008-05-09 
2007-08-27      2008-05-09  
2012-01-01      2018-07-31 
2013-01-06      2019-03-25
```

What would be the correct sql syntax to just select startdate, enddate which will be later pluged in a function to calculate the number of days for each employment?

Here's my expected result:

```
1st row: startdate 8/27/2007, enddate 5/9/2008 
2nd row: startdate 1/1/2012, enddate 3/25/2019
```

The second employment took place during the same time for the 1st employment so, it will not be counted. The fourth employment started before the third employment ended so we should use the startdate for the third employment and enddate for the fourth employment

Comment: All of these records are about one person? If yes, why you have duplicated rows?

Comment: Does it matter for the total if date ranges overlap, or have duplicates? You could include the result you expect from the sample data.

Comment: @LukStorms yes it does matter. as you see the first and the second employments started at the first time so, they should be counted only once which will total in 259 days of employments. Third and fourth employments should total in 2640 days.

Comment: @SiamakFerdos yes. this person has 4 part time jobs. first and second employments are two different jobs.

Comment: In this case there is not a single startdate and a single enddate. So what do you expect the solution to return?

Comment: @forpas
1st row: startdate 8/27/2007, enddate 5/9/2008 
2nd row: startdate 1/1/2012, enddate 3/25/2019
The second employment (from my question) took place during the same time for the 1st employment so, it will not be counted.
The fourth employment started before the third employment ended so we should use the startdate for the third employment and enddate for the fourth employment. I hope that does make sense!

Answer (score 0):

Use Distinct to remove dplicated records. Then you can use this query:

```
Select totaldays / 365 from 
(Select Sum(
    DATEDIFF(day, srartdate, enddate )
    ) As totaldays
 )
```

Comment: thanks for the help but, this's not what I'm looking for. as I mentioned there's a function that has some special logic which takes the startdate and enddate as parameters. I just need help figuiring out the correct way to select the startdate, enddate.
my expected outpout would be:
1st row: startdate 8/27/2007, enddate 5/9/2008
2nd row: startdate 1/1/2012, enddate 3/25/2019

Comment: You can nothave unique startdate and enddate. You should calc them record by record which is not important they making via function or using in a function , ... . Otherwise complete your question with ur logics and function and expected resuls

Answer (score 0):

This query returns the dates without overlapping:

```
select 
  v.startdate startdate,
  min(vv.enddate) enddate
from view_appemployment v 
inner join view_appemployment vv 
on v.startdate <= vv.enddate
and not exists (
  select * from view_appemployment vvv 
  where vv.enddate >= vvv.startdate and vv.enddate < vvv.enddate
) 
where not exists (
  select * from view_appemployment vvvv 
  where v.startdate > vvvv.startdate and v.startdate <= vvvv.enddate
) 
group by v.startdate
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f257f23fbd5ec59b79bf8225397b4c67)
Results:

```
startdate           | enddate            
 ------------------ | ------------------
27/08/2007 00:00:00 | 09/05/2008 00:00:00
01/01/2012 00:00:00 | 25/03/2019 00:00:00
```

Comment: it will take me sometime to process the logic you wrote but, not sure why I'm not getting any data back when I specify the id for that user. so if I add AND UserID = 100 I don't get any data back.

Comment: This code assumes operates on view_appemployment. So if you want a `where id = ?` it must be plugged in every occurrence of view_appemployment, like: `select * from view_appemployment where id = ?`

Comment: Got it. In which part should I add the ISNULL check to replace the enddate with getdate(). actually the way I have the data set up is the fourth employment has no enddate. in this case it should be replaced with today's date

Comment: Everywhere you see enddate you must do: coalesce(enddate, CONVERT (date, GETDATE()))

Comment: Got it. how would i incroporate this part which was part of the original query I used in the past:
Age18 is selecting the user date of birth from another table.
and (
  (StartDate >= Age18)
  OR
  (StartDate < Age18 --Individual started position before becoming 18
  AND (EndDate > Age18  OR EndDate IS NULL) --position ended after he trurned 18 or still working at same position
  AND DATEDIFF(YYYY,App.BirthDate, GETDATE()) > 18) -- Individual is now  18 years old 
  )

Comment: This is different case. Post another question with all the relevant sample data and expected results and explain in details what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Gaps & Islands in Sequences problem, the following query should do what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE #emp (empid int, startdate date,enddate date)
INSERT INTO #emp VALUES
(1,'2007-08-27','2008-05-09'),
(1,'2007-08-27','2008-05-09'),
(1,'2012-01-01','2018-07-31'),
(1,'2013-01-06','2019-03-25')

;WITH starts AS (
    SELECT em.*,
            (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                            FROM #emp em2
                            WHERE em2.EmpID = em.EmpID AND
                                    em2.StartDate < em.StartDate AND
                                    em2.EndDate >= em.StartDate
                            ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS [IsStart]
    FROM #emp em )

SELECT EmpID
    ,MIN(StartDate) AS [StartDate]
    ,MAX(EndDate) AS [EndDate]
FROM (SELECT s.*, SUM(isstart) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY StartDate) AS [grp]
      FROM starts s
     ) s
GROUP BY EmpID, grp
ORDER BY EmpID
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

[image: RESULT PIC]

```
SELECT concat(id," row: start date ",date_format(start_date,'%d/%m/%y'),"   end date ",date_format(end_date,'%d/%m/%y'))as dateinfo FROM `dates`
```